# How does one get the query parameters in an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

In the book "Web development with Node.js and Express", there is the following snippet:

```
app.post('/process', function(req, res){
if(req.xhr || req.accepts('json,html')==='json'){
        // if there were an error, we would send { error: 'error description' }
res.send({ success: true }); 
}else{
        // if there were an error, we would redirect to an error page
        res.redirect(303, '/thank-you');
    }
});
```

In the else block, we can do something like:

```
    console.log('Form (from querystring): ' + req.query.form);
    console.log('CSRF token (fconsolerom hidden form field): ' + req.body._csrf);
    console.log('Name (from visible form field): ' + req.body.name); 
    console.log('Email (from visible form field): ' + req.body.email);
```

And we would get the values. But if we put the same block in the if block, the values are all 'undefined' (because it is an ajax request). So how do we read the request parameters when it is an ajax request ?

EDIT: I am using, express, and "Body Parser"

EDIT: My jQuery code for making the ajax request:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('.signupform').on('submit', function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            var action = $(this).attr('action');
            var $container = $(this).closest('.formContainer'); $.ajax({
                url: action,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.success){ $container.html('<h2>Thank you!</h2>');
                }else{
                    $container.html('There was a problem.');
                } 
            },
                error: function(){
                    $container.html('There was a problem.');
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` of request in ajax? And what sort of middleware are you employing in order to process the body parameter? As much I know your query parameter `req.query.form` should not be undefined as long as you are doing `post` on `/process?form=sth`

Comment: And another thing, please don't refer your question to a book. There are a lot of people who do not know about that book.

Comment: @Tolsee I posted my client jquery code for making the request. I'm not sure what you meant by content type of the request. Its a form post using jquery(see code in question)

Comment: Can you try submitting your form like this? https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery. This will work if you are using `JSON` parser of `Body-Parser`.

Comment: @Tolsee So I'm using Node.js with express, so I was just wondering, when the request comes into the process route, how do I process it ? Do you have an example I can look at ?

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you're adding any parameters to your Ajax request, are they included in the `action`? Check the request in your browser dev tools, make sure the `form=sth` is actually there. If the parameter is on the URL it is a very different scenario to if the parameter is part of the request body, which one are you trying to achieve? You need to show the code for the relevant middleware, just saying that you're 'using body parser' doesn't allow us to confirm that you're using it correctly in this scenario.

Comment: @skirtle The jquery code i pasted above is intercepting the submission. As for body parser, I do: var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());